# Guice: how do you configure an @Provides and @Singleton in a module in this case?

Tags: guice

I have a provider method in a module annotated with `@Provides`:

```
@Provides
public ChatServicePerformanceMonitor getChatServicePerfMon() {
  ...
}
```

and I have annotated my `ChatServicePerformanceMonitor` with `@Singleton`. In my code, where I use this instance, I can't have guice "passively" inject it, due to a framework I'm using that's constructing the enclosing class (it does not use Guice, so this is the only way I know of to get the reference):

```
chatServicePerfMon = injector.getInstance(ChatServicePerformanceMonitor.class);
```

It seems Guice does not respect the `@Singleton` annotation on my `ChatServicePerformanceMonitor` class. I get an instance for every call to injector.getInstance(ChatServicePerformanceMonitor.class).

Adding the `@Singleton` to the provider method seems to fix this:

```
@Provides @Singleton
public ChatServicePerformanceMonitor getChatServicePerfMon() {
  ...
}
```

Is that the expected behavior? It seems an `@Singleton` on the instance should be all I would need.

Comment: How are you creating the `ChatServicePerformanceMonitor` in your first code snippet? If Guice isn't creating it inside your `getChatServicePerfMon` method then the `@Singleton` will be ignored.

Comment: Yes, it's constructed inside that @Provider method, almost exactly as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) in the provideTransactionLog method. Seems like it must be something I'm doing, as someone else must have had this issue. But I can't see anything that's not really different from their examples, other than I'm getting the instance directly from an injector.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're creating the `ChatServicePerformanceMonitor` like this:

```java
@Provides
public ChatServicePerformanceMonitor getChatServicePerfMon() {
  return new ChatServicePerformanceMonitor();
}
```

then your class level `@Singleton` annotation will have no effect because Guice isn't creating the object, you are. Guice can only enforce scope on objects it creates. There's nothing wrong with adding `@Singleton` to your `getChatServicePerfMon()` method.

If you have a no-argument constructor (or an `@Inject` constructor) on the `ChatServicePerformanceMonitor` class and you remove your `@Provides` method then continual calls to the injector will return the same singleton.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am doing a new in there. I guess since Guice is calling my provider method, I thought it would still enforce the Singleton behavior (since I don't call the provider method, they do) and could manage that. Guess I was wrong!

Comment: I don't know which framework you're using but you could also use Guice to create the enclosing instance (even though you can't inject into it) via a `Provider` (or `@Provides`). That way that object can collaborate with other Guice dependencies.

Comment: Thansk, yes, i dug around for a way to do that for a while, but the way this framework "works" is I extend one of their classes. They bootstrap everything when they startup (it's a game server called SmartFox), and they do the extension class instantiation. I don't think there's a way to have Guice intercept that, is there?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: When using DI/Guice, never use the word "new".

Comment: "Guice can only enforce scope on objects it creates"

Guice is creating the object.

It's just calling our `Provides` method instead of calling the class constructor.  I see no reason why it couldn't honor the `@Singleton` class annotation in this case.

Answer (score 31):

In the meantime this feature is available (tested with Guice 4.0).

`@Provides` methods may now be also annotated with `@Singleton` to apply scope. See https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes

Answer (score -6):

You could always just do the dead-simple approach:

```
private ChatServicePerformanceMonitor perfMon = null;

@Provides
public ChatServicePerformanceMonitor getChatServicePerfMon() {
  if (perfMon == null) {
    perfMon = new ChatServicePerformanceMonitor();
  }

  return perfMon;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem threadsafe, should include synchronized keyword on method